# Add Azure network firewall rule with Bash

Tags: azure

I am creating new Azure network firewall rule with bash on Azure CLI. I put all information regarding Network rule. i.e., resource group, firewall name, collection name, etc. After this issue i am giving policy argument. But it did not accept.

Creating rule collection 'Local-Traffic-policy'.
(AzureFirewallPolicyAndRuleCollectionsConflict) Request parameter Firewall Policy FirewallPolicy and Rule Collection NetworkRuleCollections cannot coexist for the Azure Firewall /subscriptions/5ae002/resourceGroups/Admin_RGP/providers/Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/Azure-Firewall.
Code: AzureFirewallPolicyAndRuleCollectionsConflict
Message: Request parameter Firewall Policy FirewallPolicy and Rule Collection NetworkRuleCollections cannot coexist for the Azure Firewall /subscriptions/fd064/resourceGroups/Admin_RGP/providers/Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/Azure-Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error like below:***

[image]

***Note*** that: For the same Azure firewall resource, neither a firewall policy nor a rule collection can exist. *Your error indicates that FirewallPolicy and Rule Collection NetworkRuleCollections cannot coexist for the Azure Firewall* try to create firewall without policy like below:

```
az network firewall create \
    --name <TEST> \
    --resource-group <RGNAME>  \
    --location eastus
az network public-ip create \
    --name fw-pip \
    --resource-group <RGNAME>   \
    --location eastus \
    --allocation-method static \
    --sku standard
az network firewall ip-config create \
    --firewall-name <Tes1> \
    --name <config> \
    --public-ip-address fw-pip \
    --resource-group  az network firewall    \
    --vnet-name Test-FW-VN
az network firewall update \
    --name Test1 \
    --resource-group <RGNAME>  
az network public-ip show \
    --name fw-pip \
    --resource-group  <RGNAME>  
fwprivaddr="$(az network firewall ip-config list -g Test-FW-RG -f Test-FW01 --query "[?name=='FW-config'].privateIpAddress" --output tsv)"
```

[image]

Now I added Application rule collection , Network rule collection like below:

```
az network firewall application-rule create \
   --collection-name <Coll01> \
   --firewall-name <Test-FW01> \
   --name Allow-Google \
   --protocols Http=80 Https=443 \
   --resource-group <RGNAME>   \
   --target-fqdns www.google.com \
   --source-addresses 10.0.2.0/24 \
   --priority 200 \
   --action Allow
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

***Network Firewall Rule***

```
az network firewall network-rule create \
   --collection-name <Net-Coll01> \
   --destination-addresses 209.244.0.3 209.244.0.4 \
   --destination-ports 53 \
   --firewall-name <Test-FW01> \
   --name Allow-DNS \
   --protocols UDP \
   --resource-group <RGNAME> \
   --priority 200 \
   --source-addresses 10.0.2.0/24 \
   --action Allow
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

***Reference:***

[Deploy and configure Azure Firewall using Azure CLI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/deploy-cli)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)